# Qt correct way to set z or z-index (Programmatically)

Tags: c++, qt, styles

I want to ensure that objects are layer correctly, I've read online that the way to achieve this is by setting the z-index style.

However so far I haven't been able to do this, I want to set the style programmatically.

I've tried:

```
  pobjWidget->setStyleSheet("z-index: 5");
```

and

```
  pobjWidget->setStyleSheet("z: 5");
```

Both of these result in "Unknown property z-index" or "Unknown property z" being displayed in the console.

pobjWidget is an a pointer to a QWidget.

The reason I need this is that I'm rendering widgets with a transparent background onto live video widgets and I need to ensure that the widgets on top do not flicker, this is an attempt to illuminate the flicker.

Comment: use  pobjWidget->raise()

Comment: @Programmer_ARM, raise isn't good enough, it just promotes the widget calling it to the very top, I need to define the order

Comment: But if you know the required widget order from back to front `a, b, c, ..., z` you can simply do `a->raise(); b->raise(); ...; z->raise();`, right?

Comment: If you have to resort to manual layering your ui is probably not structured correctly. That's the wrong way to fix it IMO

Comment: Why is child/parent relationship not sufficient for your application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you have a handle to every widget you want to order. If raise and lower are too crude for you, you can use

```
void QWidget::stackUnder(QWidget *w)
```

Quoting from the docs: "Places the widget under w in the parent widget's stack.
To make this work, the widget itself and w must be siblings."

The important bit is that they must be siblings, i.e. need to have the same QObject as parent.